# Android-org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Am a new comer in Android.I am trying to connect MySQL for store values from android application.But am having problems connecting to my server.please help me..?.

**Error:org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond**
here is the code:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.easyeop;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,OnItemSelectedListener{

    EditText ename;
    String date;
    Spinner category;
    Spinner product;
    Spinner merchant;
    EditText qty;
    Spinner unit;
    EditText rate;
    TextView vals;
    double value;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private Button mSubmit;
    private Button mCancel;
    private String spinner_category[];
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private static String registerURL = "http://223.185.164.105:8080/mywebs/index.php";
    private static String register_tag = "register";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ename=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.eename);
        category=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        product=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        merchant=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        qty=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.eqty);
        unit=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
        rate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.erate);
        vals=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.dvalue);


        mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

        mCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        mCancel.setOnClickListener(this);

        spinner_category=new String[2];
        spinner_category[0]="Category11";
        spinner_category[1]="Category22";


        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerCategory = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinner_category);
        category.setAdapter(spinnerCategory);
        category.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerProduct = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[] {
                        new String("Product1"), new String("Product2") });
        product.setAdapter(spinnerProduct);
        product.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerMerchant = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[] {
                        new String("Ajith"), new String("Piyush") });
        merchant.setAdapter(spinnerMerchant);
        merchant.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerUnit = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[] {
                        new String("KG"), new String("Tons") });
        unit.setAdapter(spinnerUnit);
        unit.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
    class saveNewData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Saving Details...!");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Do In Background...");
            String name=ename.getText().toString();
            String cat=category.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String prd=product.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String mer=merchant.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String qt=qty.getText().toString();
            String uni=unit.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String rat=rate.getText().toString();
            Date d=new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            date=format.format(d);                  
            // Building Parameters
            System.out.println("bfr building params");
             List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tdate", date));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", cat));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product", prd));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("merchant", mer));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qty", qt));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("unit", uni));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rate", rat));

                System.out.println("aftr building params");

             // getting JSON Object
                // Note that save details url accepts POST method
                System.out.println("save details url accepts POST method...");
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(registerURL,
                        "POST", params);
                System.out.println("aftr save details url accepts POST method...");
                // check log cat for response
                Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
                System.out.println("create response...");
                // check for success tag
                try {
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully saved details
                        System.out.println("successfully saved...");
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                        // closing this screen
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        // failed to save details
                        System.out.println("failed to save details...");
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            return null;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.cancel:
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // finish();
            break;          
        case R.id.submit:
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // creating new product in background thread
            System.out.println("Inside Submit");
            new saveNewData().execute();                
        break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }
}
```

JSONParser.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET method
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                System.out.println("method=post");
//              HttpParams httpParameters=new BasicHttpParams();
//              int timeoutConnection = 3000;               
//              HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,timeoutConnection);
//                int timeoutSocket = 5000;
//                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);                
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();


            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }          

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            System.out.println("UnsupportedEncodingException..."+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            System.out.println("ClientProtocolException..."+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException..."+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
12-31 11:44:47.718: D/ddm-heap(220): Got feature list request
12-31 11:48:15.258: W/KeyCharacterMap(220): No keyboard for id 0
12-31 11:48:15.258: W/KeyCharacterMap(220): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
12-31 11:48:29.128: I/System.out(220): Inside Submit
12-31 11:48:29.259: I/System.out(220): Do In Background...
12-31 11:48:29.259: I/System.out(220): name :hfdw
12-31 11:48:29.259: I/System.out(220): category :Category11
12-31 11:48:29.259: I/System.out(220): product :Product1
12-31 11:48:29.259: I/System.out(220): merchant :Ajith
12-31 11:48:29.259: I/System.out(220): qty :445
12-31 11:48:29.259: I/System.out(220): unit :KG
12-31 11:48:29.259: I/System.out(220): rate :67
12-31 11:48:30.009: I/System.out(220): date :31-12-2012
12-31 11:48:30.020: I/System.out(220): bfr building params
12-31 11:48:30.239: I/System.out(220): aftr building params
12-31 11:48:30.309: I/System.out(220): save details url accepts POST method...
12-31 11:48:30.318: I/System.out(220): method=post
12-31 11:48:30.580: I/System.out(220): send params
12-31 11:48:30.828: D/dalvikvm(220): GC freed 3512 objects / 211920 bytes in 139ms
12-31 11:48:35.178: D/dalvikvm(220): GC freed 316 objects / 194992 bytes in 114ms
12-31 11:48:39.218: I/System.out(220): IOException...org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
12-31 11:48:39.228: E/IO Exception(220): Errorrr
12-31 11:48:39.228: W/System.err(220): org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
12-31 11:48:39.290: W/System.err(220):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:85)
12-31 11:48:39.298: W/System.err(220):  at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
12-31 11:48:39.326: W/System.err(220):  at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:179)
12-31 11:48:39.338: W/System.err(220):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
12-31 11:48:39.348: W/System.err(220):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
12-31 11:48:39.348: W/System.err(220):  at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
12-31 11:48:39.370: W/System.err(220):  at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
12-31 11:48:39.370: W/System.err(220):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:410)
12-31 11:48:39.370: W/System.err(220):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
12-31 11:48:39.370: W/System.err(220):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-31 11:48:39.370: W/System.err(220):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
12-31 11:48:39.370: W/System.err(220):  at com.example.easyeop1.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:57)
12-31 11:48:39.370: W/System.err(220):  at com.example.easyeop1.MainActivity$saveNewData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:159)
12-31 11:48:39.370: W/System.err(220):  at com.example.easyeop1.MainActivity$saveNewData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
12-31 11:48:39.370: W/System.err(220):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-31 11:48:39.370: W/System.err(220):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-31 11:48:39.370: W/System.err(220):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-31 11:48:39.370: W/System.err(220):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
12-31 11:48:39.378: W/System.err(220):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
12-31 11:48:39.378: W/System.err(220):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
12-31 11:48:39.378: E/Buffer Error(220): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
12-31 11:48:39.388: E/JSON Parser(220): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of 
12-31 11:48:39.398: I/System.out(220): aftr save details url accepts POST method...
12-31 11:48:39.431: W/dalvikvm(220): threadid=17: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
12-31 11:48:39.439: E/AndroidRuntime(220): Uncaught handler: thread AsyncTask #1 exiting due to uncaught exception
12-31 11:48:39.459: E/AndroidRuntime(220): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-31 11:48:39.459: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
12-31 11:48:39.459: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-31 11:48:39.459: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-31 11:48:39.459: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-31 11:48:39.459: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-31 11:48:39.459: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
12-31 11:48:39.459: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
12-31 11:48:39.459: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
12-31 11:48:39.459: E/AndroidRuntime(220): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-31 11:48:39.459: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at com.example.easyeop1.MainActivity$saveNewData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:163)
12-31 11:48:39.459: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at com.example.easyeop1.MainActivity$saveNewData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
12-31 11:48:39.459: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-31 11:48:39.459: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-31 11:48:39.459: E/AndroidRuntime(220):  ... 4 more
12-31 11:48:39.489: I/dalvikvm(220): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
12-31 11:48:39.540: I/dalvikvm(220): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-31 11:48:44.939: I/Process(220): Sending signal. PID: 220 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Post your `LogCat` trace.

Comment: Do you have INTERNET permission?

Comment: 323go: No INTERNET permission would produce a `java.net.SocketException`.

Comment: @323go yup.<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem. It seems to be related to a bug in OS versions prior to ICS - or was in my case. Which android version are you running?

This block of code fixed the issue for me (reference: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13117#c14)

```
private void workAroundReverseDnsBugInHoneycombAndEarlier(HttpClient client) {
    // Android had a bug where HTTPS made reverse DNS lookups (fixed in Ice Cream Sandwich) 
    // http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13117
    SocketFactory socketFactory = new LayeredSocketFactory() {
        SSLSocketFactory delegate = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
        @Override public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
            return delegate.createSocket();
        }
        @Override public Socket connectSocket(Socket sock, String host, int port,
                InetAddress localAddress, int localPort, HttpParams params) throws IOException {
            return delegate.connectSocket(sock, host, port, localAddress, localPort, params);
        }
        @Override public boolean isSecure(Socket sock) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            return delegate.isSecure(sock);
        }
        @Override public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port,
                boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
            injectHostname(socket, host);
            return delegate.createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
        }
        private void injectHostname(Socket socket, String host) {
            try {
                Field field = InetAddress.class.getDeclaredField("hostName");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                field.set(socket.getInetAddress(), host);
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
        }
    };
    client.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry()
            .register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the error is `NoHttpResponseException`, I would guess the error is due to a problem in your network or a overly loaded server!

Comment: :-sir overly loaded server means?how to resolve that problem?

Comment: Are you sure that the url you mention `http://223.185.164.105:8080/mywebs/index.php` is correct? Have you tried testing the POST request with alternative REST-clients such as [Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/)?

Comment: sir I have no static IP.I will change the IP everytime when I connect to the Internet.

Comment: It is pretty difficult to just guess. Post some logs from `logcat` and `wireshark` if possible. It would be better if you just try with alternative REST clients and check if you get the result.

Comment: Well looking at your `logcat` and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703689/android-org-apache-http-nohttpresponseexception-the-target-server-failed-to-re), shows quite a bit of similarity. If you are facing the same problem, you could recheck the way you set your POST header parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/ to replace httpclient prior to android 4.0 (ICS),I fixed this bug by using this jar.